# Load different view for different device on UITabBarController load

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, nib

i have a **tabbar** controller created by *interface builder*. It has 5 tab with 5 views.
Now i can porting this project in *ipad compatible version*.

Using xcode and IB i created the correct views for ipad with "*create ipad version using autosizing masks*".
I have `TestView_iPad.xib` and `TestView.xib`

Ok!

Now, **how can i load at startup in my tabbar controller the iphone or ipad correct nib file**??? What is the right way?
I need to do this in my *testview controller* or in my *appdelegate*?
I recognize the devices correctly, but i not able to load from *different nib file*, because it where setted from interface builder (Nib Name = "TestView" from Inspector)!

someone have a trick?

thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my iOS app, I use two different NIBs and yes, they both have UITabBarControllers. The way I do it is by adding a key to my Info.plist: `Main nib file base name (iPad)` and copy the iPhone xib and rename it (Example: TabBar_iPad.xib) Then add your new xib's name as the value for `Main nib file base name (iPad)` and enter the xib's name destined for the iphone under the key `Main nib file base name (iPhone)`

It works great!